# I was debugging a C program using gdb and I get the following output when I check the value of a variable. What does it signify?

Tags: c, debugging

**Code:**

```
int a;
int b;
char test[011];
a = 0x41414141;
b = 0x42424242;
```

**gdb output**

```
(gdb) x/s &a
0x7fffffffde1c: "AAAA@\336\377\377\377\177"
(gdb) x/s &b
0x7fffffffde18: "BBBBAAAA@\336\377\377\377\177"
```

In the code **a** is initialised with **AAAA** and **b** with **BBBB**.
I need to know the following.

1. Why the location of b has **BBBBAAAA** instead of **BBBB** it is supposed to have?
2. What does the **@\336\377\377\377\177** signify?

Answer (score 4):

> Why the location of `b` has BBBBAAAA instead of BBBB it is supposed to have?

It doesn't. The location of b has 0x42424242 (when interpreted as an `int`). But by running `x/s &b` (as opposed to `print b`) you are telling gdb to print a string starting at the location of `b`, rather than to print the `int` stored there.

It so happens that the bytes stored at the location of `b` look like "BBBB" when interpreted as ASCII, and the bytes after that look like "AAAA@" when interpreted as ASCII, and then there are some more bytes that aren't printable characters so gdb prints them as escape codes instead, and then there's a 0 byte (which indicates the end of a string).

> What does the @\336\377\377\377\177 signify?

@ is the character @. \336 and \337 and \177 are escape codes - the bytes following the @ aren't displayable characters, so gdb prints them as octal escape codes instead (using C syntax).